# Htaccess rewrite with question mark in condition

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all

```
homepage.com/?start=
```

to

```
homepage.com
```

but not all other urls with ?start= such as

```
homepage.com/xxxx/?start=
```

i tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} start [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://homepage.com? [R=301,L]
```

but sure, it redirect to home page all URLS with ?start

Comment: Make your RewriteRule only match when the requested path was “empty” - `RewriteRule ^$ http://homepage.com? [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule .* http://homepage.com? [R=301,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern*, (eg. `.*`) matches against the URL-path.

The regex `.*` matches *everything*, so that's why it redirects *every* URL-path. To match an *empty* URL-path (ie. just the home page) then restrict the regex to match an empty URL-path. eg. `^$`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bstart= [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/ [QSD,R=302,L]
```

Assuming you're on Apache 2.4 then use the `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag instead of appending an empty query string to the *substitution* string. Note that there should be a slash after the hostname portion of the URL.

Note that the regex `start` matched that string anywhere (eg. `mystart123`, `starter=`, etc.). The regex `\bstart=` matches just the query string parameter name as stated.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule